# MySqlBulkLoader decimal separator problem c#

Tags: c#, expression, decimal, separator

I have problem importing CSV file which contain number with "," as decimal separator.
I think that can be fixed using Expression property of MySqlBulkLoader class, but i don't know how.
this is my code:

```
                MySqlBulkLoader bulkLoad = new MySqlBulkLoader(mySqlCon)

                bulkLoad.Local = true;
                bulkLoad.ConflictOption = MySqlBulkLoaderConflictOption.Ignore;
                bulkLoad.TableName = "file_na";
                bulkLoad.FieldTerminator = "#";
                bulkLoad.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
                bulkLoad.FileName = naziv;
                bulkLoad.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
                i =bulkLoad.Load();
```

In CSV file one of the fields have value 1045,15.
When i import CSV into database value has been changed to 1045.00.
Im trying to replace "," with "." before loading into database.
I was found how that can be fixed in mysql, but how to fix with bulk loader class.

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE dados_meteo
(@var1, @var2)
SET column1 = REPLACE(@var1, ',', '.'), column2 = REPLACE(@var2, ',', '.')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: " CSV file which contain number with "," as decimal separator."! - ah, and how is this supposed to separate? Are the numbers paranthesis ("") or is this supposed to work by magic. The ONE char you should not use for this in a CSV is - a comma.

Comment: "When i import CSV into database value has been changed to 1045.00." - ah, if you field is a numeric field, it has no format. It is a number. The format is what you see as representation when making a query. "." looks good- it likely falls back into... an invariatn culture using english standard.

Answer (score 1):

i found solution :)
first "Allow User Variables=True" must be added in connection string
then define table columns and add expression without "set" (set col3=replace(@d,',','.'))

```
            MySqlBulkLoader bulkLoad = new MySqlBulkLoader(mySqlCon)
            {Columns={"col1","col2","@d"}
             Expressions={"col3=replace(@d,',','.')"}
            }
            bulkLoad.Local = true;
            bulkLoad.ConflictOption = MySqlBulkLoaderConflictOption.Ignore;
            bulkLoad.TableName = "file_na";
            bulkLoad.FieldTerminator = "#";
            bulkLoad.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
            bulkLoad.FileName = naziv;
            bulkLoad.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
            i =bulkLoad.Load();
```